# Through ssh connecting to ec2 instance error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

1. ssh -i AWSKeyPair.pem ec2-user@ipaddress
2. Error Permission denied (publickey).
3. pem file is valid file for to connect an ec2 instance.
4. ssh -v -i AWSKeyPair.pem ec2-user@ipaddress
5. debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
6. debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
7. debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
8. debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST
               sent
9. debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received debug1:
                   Authentications that can continue: publickey debug1: Next

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I am getting this error debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker when i am connecting to aws ec2 instance server

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete debug trace produced by "ssh -v", or even better add a "v": ssh -vv -i ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Kindly Check if ssh port is allowed in security group or not for the machine from which you are doing ssh.
2. If you believe the key is correct then i would suggest you to convert that .pem file to .ppk and then try to connect with putty from your machine.
   For which you have to open 22 port from you specified ip address in security group.
3. Kindly check your .pem file permission whether it is read only or not. If it is read only then kindly change file permission to 644 and then try.

Answer (score 0):

chmod 600 AWSKeyPair.pem

and then try connecting again.